# Junit plugin test runner doesn't seem load the test classes as a bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am trying to do something very simple.

I have two bundles (plugin projects) in eclipse. One contains tests that reference the other. I'd like to get at the bundle context in my test. I thought framework util could be co-opted for this purpose. However whatever class I use, the loaded bundle context is always null, implying that the class isn't in a loaded bundle.

Does anyone have a minimal PDE project workspace that demonstrates how to do this?

When I get home I will create a minimal failing example  if the collective wisdom of stack overflow hasn't solved the problem before I get off this train.

Answer (score 1):

See http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/600-testing.html for an example if running JUnit test from inside a bundle.

Normal JUnit runner will not package up the test classes in a bundle, install them and their (unknown) dependencies in a framework. They will just run in a plain Java environment.

To run JUnit test from inside a bundle, use support like that in Bnd as mentioned in the link above.